# Ionic 4 Page animation

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I don’t know what’s happening, but when I use the ionic router `navigateForward` or `navigateBack` methods

their is no animation , just the page appears without animate

```
this.navCtrl.navigateBack(HomePage);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used [Native Page Transition plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-page-transitions) to fix this problem